# Upper and lower bound on characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

> Let $\chi_{[a, b]} = 1$ when $x \in [a, b]$ and $0$ otherwise. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and show that there are compactly supported and smooth functions $f, g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ such that we have

> $$f \leq \chi_{[a, b]} \leq g.$$

> Also show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} (f - g)dx < \epsilon$.

I understand the problem "visually" and intuitively, i.e. if I draw the graph of $\chi$ on some interval $[a, b]$, then $f$ must be equal to $1$ within the interval $[a, b]$ and then smoothly become $0$ once we move outside the interval. Whereas $g$ must be $1$ inside $[a, b]$ but smoothly vanish inside $[a, b]$. And then the area of the difference of these two functions must be arbitrarily small.

But I can't seem to be able to make this into a rigorous argument. I tried defining $f$ piecewise such that $f(x) = 1$ when $x \in [a, b]$ and then I would need some term that makes $f$ vanish when $x$ is outside of $[a, b]$.

Comment: What do you know of compactly supported smooth functions?

Comment: I know that compact support means that the support is compact, i.e. in $\mathbb{R}$ this means closed and bounded. I also know that a compactly supported smooth function is a bump function and a bump function is equal to $1$ on a (given) compact set.

Comment: Do you know an explicit example of one?

Comment: Just the example from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

Comment: That’s the one I would have said too :) Here’s how I’d solve the problem. Make a $C^0$ version with piecewise straight lines that answers the question. Then convolve with above known nice function, rescaled in an appropriate way with a parameter $\lambda$ so that when $\lambda \ll 1$,  the function is basically the indicator of [a,b] (this is to get the “also” part of the question). Does that give enough ‘structure’ to get you started in writing the proof?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it myself and get back if I have any issues or if your hints were not enough.

Comment: It’s probably better to do the epsilon thing first with $C^0$ functions, and then choose $\lambda \ll \epsilon$ to finish. (Sorry, getting ready to leave for food :) ) good luck! Also “mollify/mollifier” are words to search with

Comment: @CalvinKhor I am completely stuck on this one. Can you write out an answer perhaps?

Comment: There was a typo in my construction, which made the function not $C^0$. Sorry :) I remedied this and as a verification, added a plot

Comment: @CalvinKhor I did not check the details fully. Will do it later today and also construct $g$ following your method. BTW the last picture is precisely what I had in mind when I wrote above that I understand the set up of the solution visually/intuitively. Thanks! If any questions arise, then I will come back.

Comment: I simplified the construction, there's no need to have an intermediate $C^0$ function when you are mollifying....! serves me right for multitasking, sorry for the unneeded complexity. Edited the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets write $X=\chi_{a,b}$. To get $f$, you just need to mollify an indicator of a smaller set, say $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]$ (where $\epsilon\ll 1$),
$$ \tilde f(x) := \chi_{[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]}\le X.$$ Then take the standard mollifier $\phi_\epsilon(x) = \frac1{\epsilon}\phi(\frac x\epsilon)$ where $\phi$ is your favourite non-negative $C^\infty_c$ function with integral 1. Any choice will work (with slightly different details) but  I’ll choose one  with support in $[-1,1]$. Then $\phi_\epsilon$ is supported in $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ and also has integral $1$. Now form the convolution
$$f (x):= \tilde f*\phi_\epsilon(x)= 
\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \tilde  f(x-y) \phi_{\epsilon}(y) dy = \int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} \tilde f(y) \phi_{\epsilon}(y-x) dy.  $$
Since both $\tilde f$ and $\phi_\epsilon$ have compact support, so does $f_\epsilon$. In fact, the support of the convolution is the sum of the supports, i.e. $\operatorname{supp }f= [a+\epsilon-\epsilon,b-\epsilon+\epsilon] = [a,b]$, so it turns out that I have the largest possible support for $f$ though this is of course not required. It is standard to check that $f$ is $C^\infty$; all derivatives can be made to fall on $\phi_\epsilon$. So one just needs to check that we have $f \le X$. This is because $\phi_\epsilon(y-x)dy$ acts to average the points $\epsilon$-close to $x$. If all the points $x$ on this set are less than $1$, then so is their average. So $0\le f\le X=1$ on $[a,b]$ (the support of $f$) and $f=X=0$ outside $[a,b]$.

One can bound the integral $\int X - f dx = \int |X-f|dx$ by drawing rectangles; one gets the bound 1 times the size of the set where they are different; this is $4\epsilon$.

Playing a similar game, we can construct $\tilde g=\chi_{[a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon]}\ge X$ and then mollify to get $g$, finishing the proof (we get the bound $\int (g-f)\le 8\epsilon$ but one can go back and use $\epsilon/8$ instead. Strictly speaking, the inequality in the question is also satisfied: $\int (f-g)\le 0 \le \epsilon$ ).

Here's a plot:  ([interactive Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ksivrrbumm))

[image]